# Convert reduced density matrix in A.O. basis from GAMESS to pyscf

Tags: computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, pyscf, gamess

I want pyscf to read the single-particle reduced density matrix computed by GAMESS.
However, I am having trouble because the matrix sizes in GAMESS and pyscf are different.
For example, the AO-displayed matrix in GAMESS are of the form 25 times 25 for a single molecule of H2O using the cc-pvdz basis function.

The matrix indexes of GAMESS are shown below.

```
    1  O  1  S   
    2  O  1  S   
    3  O  1  S   
    4  O  1  X   
    5  O  1  Y   
    6  O  1  Z   
    7  O  1  X   
    8  O  1  Y   
    9  O  1  Z   
   10  O  1 XX   
   11  O  1 YY   
   12  O  1 ZZ   
   13  O  1 XY   
   14  O  1 XZ   
   15  O  1 YZ
   16  H  2  S   
   17  H  2  S   
   18  H  2  X   
   19  H  2  Y   
   20  H  2  Z
   21  H  3  S   
   22  H  3  S   
   23  H  3  X   
   24  H  3  Y   
   25  H  3  Z
```

On the other hand, in pyscf, the density matrix for a single molecule of H2O with the same basis function takes the form 24times 24.
This is probably because pyscf uses five different basis functions(d$_{xy}$, d$_{yz}$, d$_{zx}$, d$_{x^2-y^2}$, d$_{z^2}$) to display d orbitals, while GAMESS uses six different basis functions, XX, YY, ZZ, XY, XZ, and YZ.

Is there any way to convert a density matrix obtained in GAMESS using 6 different bases, XX, YY, ZZ, XY, XZ, YZ for the d orbitals, to a representation using 5 general basis functions(d$_{xy}$, d$_{yz}$, d$_{zx}$, d$_{x^2-y^2}$, d$_{z^2}$)?

Comment: See https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8343/transforming-basis-functions-from-cartesian-to-speherical, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9133/how-to-build-cartesian-representations-of-spherical-gaussian-basis-functions/9135#9135

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I can solve the problem by referring to it.

Comment: I'm not a pyscf person at all but on https://pyscf.org/pyscf_api_docs/pyscf.gto.html there are references to functions called things like pyscf.gto.mole.cart2sph which look interesting

Comment: @user2436 did you figure it out? Are you still working on it? Please update us!